# Importing and formatting photos

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a button that opens the dialogue box and allows the user to:

- select a photo from their files,
- embeds that file to the particular cell that the button exists in,
- and allows it to move and size along with that cell, while maintaining aspect ratio (thanks for the pickup dbmitch)

I used the `expression.Insert.Picture()` method. When I sent the sheet the pictures were replaced with:

> Photo has been moved, deleted or edited.

It seems this method links the file.

Now I'm trying the older method of `expression.shapes.addPicture()`.
I think I am successfully adding the photo.
I can't get the sizing or locking to cell to work. Both attempts below.

```vb
Sub GetPic()
Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
Dim img As Picture
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select Picture To Be Imported")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
    Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fNameAndPath)
    With img
        'Resize Picture to fit in the range....
        .Left = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Left
        .Top = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Top
        .Width = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Width
        .Height = ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Height
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End Sub


Sub TestPic()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ' Insert the image.
    Set s = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please work"), _
      False, True, ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Left, _
      ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Top, _
      ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Width, _
      ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Height)
    ' Use picture's height and width.
End Sub
```

Comment: What does `can't seem to get the sizing or locking to cell` mean?

Comment: Remove your code that you're not using and focus on the problem code and describing what the problem actually is. You've already discovered that `Picture.Insert` doesn't insert the unlinked pic - and `.AddPicture` does.

Comment: @dbmitch "move and size with cells" is what I going for. It is a property that makes pictures/textboxes move with a cell and adjust their size accordingly. If you hide the column, the photo will too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this code to run in Excel 2016 VBA. You don't say where you're running this from but I assume Application.Caller is not from a module? Maybe a Userform?

Here's what worked for me - hopefully you can use it

```
Sub TestPic()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, s As Shape
    Dim sngLeft As Single, sngRight As Single, sngTop As Single, sngWidth As Single
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ' Insert the image.
    
    With ActiveCell.Cells
        sngLeft = .Left
        sngTop = .Top
        sngWidth = .Width
        sngheight = .Height
    End With
    
    Set s = ws.Shapes.AddPicture(Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Please work"), _
                 msoFalse, msoTrue, sngLeft, sngTop, sngWidth, sngheight)

    s.Placement = xlMoveAndSize ' move and resize when cell dimensions change
      
      'ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Left, _
      'ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Top, _
      'ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Width, _
      'ActiveSheet.Range(ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).TopLeftCell.Address).Height)
    ' Use picture's height and width.
End Sub
```

Comment: @dbmmmitch it worked! I'm still very new to VBA, although with some limited experience in other programming languages. I haven't seen the structure you used with "Dim sngLeft As Single..." so I'll have to learn a bit more about it before my next project. I sat up till after midnight on both days of my weekend trying to figure this out, so I really appreciate your help. Thanks a million mate.

Comment: @pdiddy - great news - please mark it as the answer (with the checkmark) or upvote it if helpful.

Comment: G'day @dbmitch, I've just noticed this stretches the image to fill exactly the cell, thereby distorting them beyond the point of usefulness. Any idea how I could adjust the code to  make it keep the dimension ratios?

Comment: Definitely fair, I should have included the aspect ratio preservation in the original question. I've now edited that. I've also marked your response as useful.